# How does this example of passing arrays by reference work in Perl?

Tags: arrays, perl

I was looking on a post on how to pass arrays (or lists) with scalars when I stumbled upon this S.O. post... [Passing By Value - S.O.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294324/perl-subroutine-array-and-scalar-variable-paramaters)

I found that the chosen answer solution worked, but since I am trying to learn Perl I would like to know how it worked. In this line

```
my($inVal, $inValTwo, $inArray, $inArrayTwo) = @_;
```

I see that the author is placing the input parameters that were passed to the sub program into scalar variables. Then, in this line

```
@{$inArray}
```

he said to "use the reference as arrays". What did he mean by this and what exactly is going on in the second line? I have not seen those operators combined like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing to keep in mind is that [arrays and lists are not the same](http://friedo.com/blog/2013/07/arrays-vs-lists-in-perl).

A reference is a scalar that holds the memory address of something else - an array, hash, another scalar, etc. It's a fancy kind of pointer.

Subroutines in Perl take a list of arguments (and return a list of results.) This is a common stumbling block when you want to do something like

```
mysub( @foo, @bar )
```

and then you realize that the elements of `@foo` and `@bar` got flattened into a single list in your subroutine. If you know the size of `@foo` ahead of time you can just grab the right number of elements off the beginning of the list, but usually you don't.

References can solve this problem, since they are scalars. If you pass references to `@foo` and `@bar`, you know that your subroutine will always have two parameters to deal with, regardless of the sizes of the referant arrays.

But we still need to get at the data in those arrays. To do that, we have to tell Perl to go get the thing that the references are pointing to. This is called *dereferencing.*

In Perl, there are two common ways to dereference an array reference:

1. To get the whole array, use `my @array = @$ref;`
2. To get an element in the array, use `my $elem = $ref->[42]`.

Note that the first example is sometimes written `@{ $ref }`, but the extra curlies are not required unless you need to disambiguate some nested structure. Some people prefer to always use the extra curlies but I find that they add clutter and are usually unnecessary.

For more on the exciting topic of references, check out

1. [Perl reference tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html)
2. [Perl reference reference](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html)
3. [Perl data structures cookbook](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)

Comment: Oh ok. This was extremely helpful and informative. Phenomenal answer! I have been enjoying the nice syntax of Perl and am becoming more of a fan of scripting languages in general. Thank you!

Comment: +1 for link on arrays not being lists, I learn something new everyday!

Answer (score 2):

In perl, you pass a list of scalars to subroutines.

Scalar values can be:

1. A primitive data type ie. String, Int, double
2. A reference to an array.
3. A reference to a hash

So when calling a subroutine, you can pass an entire array (because an array is a list of scalars)

```
my @list = (1, 2, 3);

#note the variable declaration being surrounded by parenthesis.
#that says use list context
sub getList {
    my ($foo, $bar, $baz) = @_; #(@_ is the list you passed to the sub)
}
```

Now, if you have 2 lists you want to pass to a subroutine, you can't do

```
getList(@listA, @listB);
```

Because the two lists will be flattened into a single array contained in `@_`.

So, to get around this, you use a reference, or pass the array as a reference.

```
my $first_list = \@listA #this points $first_list to a reference in 
                         #memory where @listA is located.

getList($first_list, \@listB);

sub getList {
    my ($foo, $bar) = @_; #$foo and $bar now point to @listA and @listB

    #To dereference these, you either have to use the -> operator to access
    #Elements, or use the form @{ }. %{ } for hashes.

    my @listA = @{ $foo };
    my @listB = @{ $bar };

    #Now they are regular arrays again!
}
```

Comment: This was a very helpful answer as well. Thank you!